# I need help to find a mistake in my Telegram redirect

Tags: php, runtime-error, telegram

I think that the problem is in my button. Because if I delete `if (isset($_POST['Form']))` empty messages coming to my bot. Here is my code below. Hope you help me.

```
<div id="modalForm" class="modal">
    <form action="" name="form" method="POST" class="modal-content">
      <h4 class="modal-title">Оставить заявку</h4>
      <p class="modal-description">Оставьте ваш номер телефона, мы перезвоним и проконсультируем по любым вопросам</p>
      <input type="hidden" name="info">
      <input type="text" class="browser-default" name="name" placeholder="Имя">
      <input type="tel" class="browser-default" name="phone" placeholder="Номер телефона" require>
      <button type="submit" name="Form" class="mainButton">Отправить</button>
      <a href="#!" class="modal-close">
        <?php get_template_part('./icons/close') ?>
      </a>
    </form>
</div>
    
<?php

if (isset($_POST['Form'])) { 
$name = $_POST['name'];
$phone = $_POST['phone'];


$token = "<MY-BOT-TOKEN>";
$chat_id = "<MY-CHAT-ID>";

$arr = array(
  'Телефон: ' => $phone,
  'Имя: ' => $name,
);

foreach($arr as $key => $value) {
  $txt .= "<b>".$key."</b> ".$value."%0A";
};

$sendToTelegram = fopen("https://api.telegram.org/bot{$token}/sendMessage?chat_id={$chat_id}&parse_mode=html&text={$txt}","r");

if ($sendToTelegram) {
  header('Location: url.html');
} else {
  echo "Error";
}
}
?>
```

Comment: You've placed your **private BOT token** in the question. I removed it, but it's still visible in the history. Consider renewing the token at @botFather to prevent other people abusing it!

Comment: Remove the name attribute from the form element or give it another name. You have the same attribute value on the button element.

Comment: @1stthomas i try to remove the name attribute or to give another name. But it still dont work(